# Compare two dates with existing date and Get values from Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL2008 to create SPs. In my procedure I want to compare three date values and get the between two dates data from table.

I'm getting two dates from my UI `@date1`, `@date2` and I have `Date3` column in my table so based on the `@date1`, `@date2` and `Date3` I want to select some data from my table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, ... from Table
where Date3 between @date1 and @date2
```

This will get you all rows from the `Table where Date3 date is >= @date1 and <= @date2`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid time stamp in the date field you can use `Select col1,col2... from table_name where Date(Date3) between @Date1 and @date2`.